# Какой хостинг брать, для telegram бота

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Хочу создать телеграмм бота.
Как я понял, нужно брать хостинг, у которых сервера не в России.
Бота я хочу делать что-то типа через Telegram APi. Что-бы телеграм через вебхук отправлял моему скрипту запрос, а я отвечал.

Не знаю, какой хостинг для этого брать.

Comment: Изучайте и узнайте.

Comment: Любой, на котором в принципе возможно запустить нужный код.

Comment: Amazon, **1$** на 720 часов работы.

Comment: Если это ваш первый бот и вам нужно протестировать его и понять как работать то можете воспользоваться бесплатным хостингом https://www.000webhost.com/

Answer (score 0):

Любой.
Любой хостинг подойдет для телеграм бота. Вообще любой (кроме, разумеется, бесплатного).
Расположение сервера тоже не играет никакой роли. Хоть в России, хоть на островах Южного Самоа.